# How to generate a button event in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In objective-c, a button event may be generated with this:

```
[button sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

How to do this in Swift?

I control-dragged to create my button:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
     println("button tapped!")    
}
```

When I type `self.button`, the autocomplete of Xcode makes it become:

```
button(sender: AnyObject)
```

If I type

```
button.sendActionsForControlEvents(controlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
```

then a compiler warning occurs:

'(AnyObject) -> ()' does not have a member named 'sendActionsForControlEvents'

Comment: With the same function: `sendActionsForControlEvents`. It is a function of `UIControl`.

Comment: Xcode autocomplete does not have `sendActionsForControlEvents`. Do I need to import `UIControl`? but `import UIControl` does not work

Comment: `UIKit` is already imported, but autocomplete does not work for `sendActionsForControlEvents`.

Comment: How is your button referenced? Is it an `@IBOutlet` from InterfaceBuilder? Or did you create it manually by code? Please provide more information. Edit your post above and include more code.

Comment: I control-dragged a button to create an `IBAction`. The above code is edited.

Comment: If you need a reference to your button ctrl-drag from InterfaceBuilder to the top of your file and create an `@IBOutlet`. Give it a name. Later in code you can reference the button via its outlet name.

Answer (score 5):

Consider this line of code:

```
button.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)
```

OR

```
button.sendActionsForControlEvents(controlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Xcode autocomplete does not have `button.sendActionsForControlEvents`. All I can get is `button(sender: AnyObject)`, but the compiler doesn't allow this. Do I need to import anything?

Comment: I am not really sure as I have never used this method. I just wrote the Swift syntax for what you had mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

**Sadly the above code does not work for Swift. Here is my code**

```
import UIKit

class TestButtonProgrammicly: UIViewController {

// Label is set to .hidden and turns on when I click the button.

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TurnOnLabel: UIButton! // ADD THIS AND this works. I hope this will help someone else with this problem. 


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // I am trying to send a Control Event to the Button to turn on the Label. 
       TurnOnLabel.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)

    }

    @IBAction func TurnOnLabel(sender: UIButton) {
        // When you click on the Button, the label turns on no problem
        Label.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: my code does not work under the ViewDidLoad. I am trying to manually send a ControlEvent to the Button so that I can turn on the Label

Comment: your code that you have listed below does not work. I am getting a error  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78962433/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-04%20at%209.52.39%20PM.png

Comment: Someone just pointed it out to me, what I was doing wrong. I did not declare my ButtonAction. Everything is now working. I declared the Label but not the button. I can not believe that i made such a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you can add action like this :

```
self.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: "FavAction:event:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

And get you event or point :

```
func FavAction(sender: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {
var touch: UITouch = event.allTouches().anyObject()
var touchPos: CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)}
```